# Import existing .java files into IntelliJ?

Tags: java, oop, intellij-idea, ide

I'm trying to import .java files into a new IntelliJ project and am really not having any luck (which includes Google, Stack, IntelliJ docs) finding out how to do so.

I create a new project, the Java SDK is configured correctly and everything works fine. The Main class of the IntelliJ project is located in a package called 'com.company', which is located in a 'src' directory. I try adding my files to the package, no go. I try dumping my files into the 'src' directory, can't instantiate any objects.

I've tried import statements to no avail.

When I try to instantiate an object of any class, a red line appears under the class name with 'Cannot resolve myClass'. myClass = all of my classes

Can somebody tell me what the missing piece is?

Comment: you should just drop these files to the folder with main class and rename headers to correct package

Comment: @nikis The main class is in a package in the 'src' folder. How would I rename the headers?

Comment: it can be done manually if the no. of files is not quite high. Just open these files and rename package on the 1st line

Comment: @nikis 1st line of what? Too vague....

Comment: @nikis Found a simpler solution, I right clicked on the Main class of my set of .java files and made one of them the 'Main'. It executes from that file and ignores the com.company package and all the rest. Thanks for your help regardless. Cheers.